# Problem understanding Datasets with keys that are not strings

Tags: dataset

I am having difficulty understanding the difference between `Dataset` with strings as keys versus using symbols as keys.

Below is a very simple toy dataset (my actual dataset is much larger and complex) where the keys are strings

```
datasetString = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "source1"|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "source2"|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "none"|>
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using an example from the documentation I extract the rows where `a < 3`

```
datasetString[Select[#a < 3 &]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Everything works fine.

Now repeat the experiment but use symbols rather than strings for the keys.

```
datasetSymbol = Dataset[{
   <|a -> 1, b -> "source1"|>,
   <|a -> 2, b -> "source2"|>,
   <|a -> 3, b -> "none"|>
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first thing I note is that the display is different.

Secondly I am unable to use the same selection process

```
datasetSymbol[Select[#a < 3 &]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since I have access to the column using

```
datasetSymbol[All, Key[a]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I tried

```
datasetSymbol[Select[#[Key[a]] < 3 &]]
```

Here no error occurred but it returned an empty dataset.

Comment: What you really need is `dataset[Select[#[a] < 3 &]]` or `dataset[Select[#[[Key [a]]] < 3 &]]`. This is not a problem of dataset, which has in this respect the same semantics as associations. The syntax `#a` is equivalent to `#["a"]`, not `#[a]`, so there is an auto-stringification happening here.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin `datasetSymbol[Select[#[a] < 3 &]]` works as does `datasetString[Select[#["a"] < 3 &]]`. I guess the question amounts to what is the black magic as to why `datasetString[Select[#a < 3 &]]` works.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Also why do the two display differently?

Comment: Re: why `datasetString[Select[#a < 3 &]]` works - this is because of the auto-stringification. The `#a` gets interpreted as `#["a"]` (try `#a // FullForm`),  by the parser. Re: *Also why do the two display differently?* - this is due to the `Dataset` type system. Try ``TypeSystem`DeduceType@{<|a -> 1, b -> "source1"|>, <|a -> 2, 
   b -> "source2"|>, <|a -> 3, b -> "none"|>}`` vs ``TypeSystem`DeduceType@{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "source1"|>, <|"a" -> 2, 
   "b" -> "source2"|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "none"|>}``, you see general `Assoc` type in the first case and more specific `Struct` in the second.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Kindly validate the answer I posted for accuracy. Feel free to edit. I am unable to locate documentation on the `TypeSystem` and do not know what the difference is between `Struct` and `Assoc` but can guess.

Comment: Looks good to me, upvoted. `TypeSystem` is undocumented, I just happen to be somewhat familiar with  `Dataset` code base. But if you look at many posts here on this site (particularly by [WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach)), you will see quite a bit on it. The basic 4 building blocks of the Dataset type system are `List`, `Tuple`, `Assoc` and `Struct`, and in some sense, `Assoc` is more general than `Struct`, although both describe association-like types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Part 1 - Syntax

The answer is that for `Associations` and `Datasets` keys that are strings have some special shortcut syntax compared to non-string keys.

Here are the two datasets:

```
datasetString = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "source1"|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "source2"|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "none"|>
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
datasetSymbol = Dataset[{
   <|a -> 1, b -> "source1"|>,
   <|a -> 2, b -> "source2"|>,
   <|a -> 3, b -> "none"|>
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In order to access a column one can use

```
Row[{datasetString[All,Key["a"]], Spacer[20], datasetSymbol[All,Key[a]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The dataset with strings as keys can be retrieved by using either of two special shortcuts

```
Row[{datasetString[All,"a"], Spacer[20], datasetString[All,#a &]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Similar to `Associations` a named column, `"a"`, is rewritten as `Key["a"]`.

The second shortcut is the construction `#a`. What appears to be the symbol `a` is converted to a string and becomes `Slot["a"]. This is documented in the [guide/Association](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html)

Thus the `Select` operator can be written as

```
datasetString[Select[#[[Key["a"]]] < 3 &]]
atasetString[Select[#["a"] < 3 &]]
datasetString[Select[#a < 3 &]]
```

for the dataset with strings as keys. Note that the last form requires that the key be a string.

The `Select` operator for the dataset with symbols as keys can use the first two forms:

```
datasetSymbol[Select[#[[Key[a]]] < 3 &]]
datasetSymbol[Select[#[a] < 3 &]]
```

### Part 2 - Type

The two datasets display differently. This is due to the `Dataset` type system.

Below are the `FullForm` of the two datasets.

```
FullForm[datasetString]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FullForm[datasetSymbol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which accounts for why they display differently.